# Column length limits are too small in WSO2IS default database schema

Tags: postgresql, wso2, database-schema, maxlength, wso2-identity-server

I am using the TenantMgtAdminService https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/managing-tenants-with-apis/ to add tenants to my local WSO2IS server (version 5.10.0 with postgresql). I have noticed the following exception being thrown in the server when setting wso2is-admin@foodcompanyad123.com (which is a valid but longer than 31 characters email address) to tenantInfoBean.admin.

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 5 INSERT INTO REG_LOG (REG_PATH, REG_USER_ID, REG_LOGGED_TIME, REG_ACTION, REG_ACTION_DATA, REG_TENANT_ID) VALUES ('/_system/governance/permission', 'wso2is-admin@foodcompanyad123.com', '2020-06-17 13:54:15.776+03', 0, NULL, 9) was aborted: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(31) Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:154)
 at org.postgresql.core.ResultHandlerDelegate.handleError(ResultHandlerDelegate.java:50)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2269)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:511)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.internalExecuteBatch(PgStatement.java:851)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:874)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeBatch(PgPreparedStatement.java:1569)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
 at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCLogsDAO.addLogRecords(JDBCLogsDAO.java:159)
 ... 3 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(31)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2533)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2268)
 ... 13 more
```

The addTenant() call is also producing the following exception if the length of the admin username plus the '@' symbol plus the tenant domain (e.g. wso2is-admin@foodcompanyad123.com@foodcompanyad123.com) is greater than 45 characters as shown in the following stack trace.

```
TID: [-1234] [TenantMgtAdminService] [2020-06-17 14:26:25,843] [9a69c7e4-661f-4713-b500-9f7e850f5c0d] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.listener.WorkflowImplTenantMgtListener} - Error occurred while adding default bps profile for tenant: gondor-pizza-4.fts org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.WorkflowImplException: Error when executing the sql query INSERT INTO WF_BPS_PROFILE(PROFILE_NAME, HOST_URL_MANAGER, HOST_URL_WORKER, USERNAME, PASSWORD, TENANT_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
 at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.dao.BPSProfileDAO.addProfile(BPSProfileDAO.java:75)
 at org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.impl.WorkflowImplServiceImpl.addBPSProfile(WorkflowImplServiceImpl.java:89)
...
...
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(45)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2533)
```

Related to the second trace above, I have found this issue https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/5460 which remains open.

What is the best way to address these issues? Do I have to modify the schema to increase the limits? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to increase the offending column length without functionality issues. However increasing column length beyond given default values will cause slight performance degradation as the index size on the column is also increased.

However that degradation should be barely noticeable on capable infrastructure.

Better to test your critical functionalities after increase on column length, for any offending columns.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In our setup we are using emails as usernames. Is there any way to know beforehand which columns we need to change other than discovering that the hard way (by getting errors every time we insert long values in limited-length columns)?